# Научиться писать документацию и хорошо комментировать код

Tags: документация, javascript, opensource, комментарии

Хочу создать свой проект на JavaScript (уже в работе), затем хочу создать для него (хоть и бесплатный) сайт где можно будет им поинтересоваться скачать и т.д. Может размещу на code.google (уже занял место). Суть: Мне рано или поздно придётся написать документацию (объекты,методы входящие в состав). И мой код должен быть доступен для скачивания (opensource) и соответственно красив. Где можно найти статьи (или стандарты) для написания документации и статьи про хорошее комментирование кода.

Comment: [Стиль кода](http://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style), [Документирование кода](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E+%D0%BA+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83&clid=1864185&lr=10830)

Comment: Мне ещё кто нибудь ответит? (Намёк на профи и мэтров :) )

Comment: @Rules у вас половина вопросов из серии "Поищите за меня, рабы." Исчерпывающий ответ дан мной 2 дня назад.

Comment: Да... если это "исчерпывающий ответ" то "Зачем же такие форумы как Хэшкод?..."

Comment: Есть спецификации от Google насколько я помню, но где они не знаю, придется поискать.

Comment: @Rules если бы да кабы‚ да во рту росли грибы, тогда был бы не рот, а целый огород.

Comment: @Shrek а что, у тебя руки чешутся?

Comment: Не люблю мусор. Для таких целей, лучше делать отдельный документ и описывать каждый шаг. А не листать бесконечные комментарии. =) ну а вообще, читаем стандарты, там все написано, как правильно это делать =)

Answer (score 1):

Документирование кода не может быть "хорошим" - оно может быть правильным и соответствующим стандартам.
Например один из них и всесторонне поддерживаемый - [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)

По поводу "контроля качества кода" - тут немного сложнее. Дело в том что для разных спецификаций и диалектов языка - разные стандарты.  И то что мы сейчас понимаем под JavaScript - это не сам язык, а различные скриптоязыки и диалекты из спецификации ECMAScript и другое - например JSX итд.
Поэтому выбор "стандарта" - зависит от конкретного проекта. Использовать для контроля можно 'lint' или 'eslint' - пакеты в npm.
А какие плагины и какие настройки к нему использовать - зависит от используемой спецификации языка, платформы и фреймфорков.