# Список @идентификаторов , TODO или что это такое?

Tags: java, c++, документация, комментарии

Я видел что в некоторых исходных кодах JS например JQuery комментируют так:

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
```

но это просто строка для людей а

```
// TODO:
```

это уже обнаруживается большинством IDE но JS не типизированный язык поэтому спрашиваю про другие например я видел в некоторых исходных кодах на Java (в основном помоему) или C++ (какой код здесь и придумал) в комментариях вставляют описания определяемых ф-ции и т.д. примерно (взял с потолка потому что не знаю что это такое и Java) так:

```
/*
 @function getSquare
 @args:
 @x int 
 @returns int
*/
int getSquare(int);
...
int getSquare(x){
  return x*x;
}
```

Что это вообще такое за @... все поисковики уже измучал не нашёл мне кажется что есть и @TODO просто в JS `@` можно опускать. Или `@` это что то типа директивы препроцессора в Java (типа `#` в c++) или это надо применять в документации а не в исходном коде?  Сильно не пинайте я уже спрашивал  [Научиться писать документацию и хорошо комментировать код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174167/javascript-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) только про JS и только @lampa сказал

> У вас что, на калькуляторе поиск сломался?

а @Котик:

> Ахаха

но это было про JS а этот вопрос про C++ Java etc. Вопрос к профессионалам объясните что за `@...` и т.д и какие можно в исходном коде и документации использовать ключевые слова

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Говоря простым языком, это называется **самодокументированием кода** в стиле `JavaDoc`.

Пример:

```
class Test {

   /**
    * Разделить одно число на другое
    * 
    * @param int x 
    * @param int y
    * @return int
    */
   public int divide(int x, int y)
   {
      return x/y;
   }
}
```

Где все, что начинается с "собачки" - называется **тегами** описания. Из примера:
Эти теги, они стандарты. Не нужно придумывать своих.

Самые основные:

```
Тег @param int x - означает какой параметер будет передам в функцию
Тег @return - означает какое возращаемое значение мы ожидаем
Тег @author - означает кто автор
Тег @copyright - Авторские права
Тег @license - Лицензия
Тег @version - Версия
```

итд их много, если нужны все в гугл: **JavaDoc Style**

JavaDoc Style используется не только в Java, но также и в C#/C/C++ и PHP для само-документирования классов и методов. Некоторые используют даже в JavaScript.

**Это нужно для того чтобы**, облегчить чтение/понимание кода. Это общепринятый стандарт/правило для документирования своего кода.

Comment: А [doxygen](http://www.google.ru/search?q=doxygen), к примеру, умеет эту документацию переваривать в RTF или HTML.

Comment: А иногда пишут без тегов

    /**
     * list_splice_init - join two lists and reinitialise the emptied list.
     * @list: the new list to add.
     * @head: the place to add it in the first list.
     *
     * The list at @list is reinitialised
     */
    static inline void list_splice_init(struct list_head *list,
            struct list_head *head)

И тоже понятно. (это фрагмент list.h из линукса).

Comment: вот, к примеру, документация по командам, которые видит `doxygen`: [Special Commands](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html)

Comment: > Это нужно для того чтобы, облегчить чтение/понимание кода.

Не совсем так. Для понимания собачки, согласитесь, не нужны. Нотация javadoc возникла с целью автоматической генерации документации по исходникам.

Comment: Спасибо! Это как раз то что мне нужно было !

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот же, [документирование кода Java](http://java-study.ru/samouchitel/37-doc). У Вас действительно поиск сломался?

Comment: @Mobyman а для C++ есть что нибудь типа того да и на английском языке?

Comment: Конечно, есть.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про полузабытый API [Java Taglet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/taglet/overview.html)